# Roslyn Create XmlText

Tags: xml, vb.net, roslyn

I have tried to creating XmlText for

```
''' <summary>
''' Any Text
''' </summary>
```

but the code shown below does not work,

```
VB.SyntaxFactory.XmlText("<summary>" & vbCrLf & "        ''' AnyText" & vbCrLf & "        '''</summary>")
```

Result

```
"&lt;summary&gt;" & vbCrLf & "        ''' AnyText" & vbCrLf & "        ''' &lt;/summary&gt;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A XmlText Element is the Text inside an XML Node - that is, the text between <summary> and </summary>. Since you use an XmlText, the texts are translated accordingly so they can be fitteted inside an XmlElement.

In order to create the desired text you can simply create an XmlElement using the SyntaxFactory and insert other XmlNodeElements like the text using the second parameter. Please note that the XmlTextNewLine element appends a comment (''' ) after the expression.

```
Dim element = VB.SyntaxFactory.DocumentationComment(
    VB.SyntaxFactory.XmlElement("summary", VB.SyntaxFactory.List(
                    New List(Of VB.Syntax.XmlNodeSyntax) From { 
                            VB.SyntaxFactory.XmlText("").AddTextTokens(
                            VB.SyntaxFactory.XmlTextNewLine(vbCrLf, true))
                            .AddTextTokens
                            (VB.SyntaxFactory.XmlTextNewLine("Any Text"+vbCrLf, true))
                 })))
```

This call would result in the following code:

```
''' <summary>
''' Any Text
''' </summary>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer was missing a "From {" to compile I added below. I could not have done with without help, thanks.

```
SyntaxFactory.DocumentationComment(
                            SyntaxFactory.XmlElement("summary", SyntaxFactory.List(
                                New List(Of Syntax.XmlNodeSyntax) From {
                                      SyntaxFactory.XmlText("").AddTextTokens(
                                        SyntaxFactory.XmlTextNewLine(vbCrLf, True)).
                                            AddTextTokens(SyntaxFactory.XmlTextNewLine("Any Text" & vbCrLf, True))
                                            }
                                            )
                                         ))
```